# How to display personal and department lead plans in Odoo treeview report for each user?

Tags: odoo, treeview, report

Odoo: Each user see different result in treeview

Hi, I want to create a report, that includes field total_lead_plan of the department, and, field personal_lead_plan of the current user ( each user will see different number)
Do you know how to show these 2 number in the tree view at the same time?

[If user is ByeB, then it should show 50 at Personal Lead(Plan)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njDsf.png)

[If user is Hello, then it should show 300 at Personal Lead(Plan)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iSsD.png)